# Title footer for Group in Setting bundle

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, settings.bundle

How can I leave a message under group type in Setting bundle ? something like this :[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/PSGroupSpecifier.html

You need to use a `FooterText` key inside your `PSGroupSpecifier` block.

Comment: Can we add this programmatically?

Answer (score 7):

Use a `FooterText` key in your `PSGroupSpecifier` like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>My App Settings</string>
    <key>FooterText</key>
    <string>My custom footer text.</string>
</dict>
```