# In group settings API, what is "customFooterText" supposed to do?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to figure out what the property "customFooterText" in https://www.googleapis.com/groups/v1/groups/groupUniqueId does.

The docs say

> Set the content of custom footer text. [..]

so I played around with it (in combination with a true "includeCustomFooter". I also tried different states of directory-wide footer in the admin-panel) because I have a use case for setting different footers for different groups, but it does not seem to do anything.

Any input would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups), `customFooterText` is used to set the content of custom footer text. The maximum number of characters is 1000. You may check this [link](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups#resource-representations) on how to use it in your code.

```
{
  ...
   "includeCustomFooter": string,
   "customFooterText": string,
  ...
}
```

You may also refer with this related thread:

- [Title footer for Group in Setting bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148858/title-footer-for-group-in-setting-bundle/41159945#41159945)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer.Thats what i thought, but in my case it doesn't do anything.. Did you implement this yourself at some point?